# How to recreate android folder in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I deleted the android folder of my flutter project (Thought I could get rid of the errors that appear while running old projects).

How can I create that android folder?
any commands?

Comment: Hm, what about creating a new flutter project with the same name in another folder. (flutter create <projectname>) and then copy the android folder in your old project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inside your project root, run:

```bash
flutter create . --platforms=android
```

This will (re) generate missing files or folders inside the android folder.

---

For all currently supported platforms:

```
flutter create . --platforms=android,windows,linux,web,macos,ios
```

Or simply:

```
flutter create .
```

---

[Flutter CLI reference](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli).

Answer (score 15):

The first command will recreate all folders like ios, android, windows, web, linux, and macos.

```
flutter create .
```

The second command will recreate android folder.

```
flutter create --platforms android .
```

The third command will recreate android and iOS folders.

```
flutter create --platforms android,ios .
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the specific question asked!

Answer (score 0):

Navigated to the root of my project and ran `flutter create`

Basically telling flutter to try and repair all the damaged and / or missing files in you project.